# Getting ArrayIndexOutofBoundException while trying to get specific data from a word doc

Tags: java, arrays, list, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to read contents from list of word documents in a directory and getting specific value which is "**Summary**" from all the files. Here is my code below. When it tries to get the 2nd file's value its throwing **Array Index out of bound exception**

Can someone help me out to get rid of this issue

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File folder = new File("C:\\Kiruba\\Test Folder\\Admin\\");
    File[] listfiles = folder.listFiles();
    for(int i = 0; i < listfiles.length; i++) {
        if(listfiles[i].isFile()) {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(listfiles[i]);
            XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(fis);
            List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphlist = docx.getParagraphs();

            for(XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphlist) {
                String summary = paragraph.getText().split("Summary: ")[1];
                System.out.println(summary);
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("There is no files in the directory");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception log would help in identifying the line which raises the exception. It seems that this line "paragraph.getText().split("Summary: ")[1]" would throw mentioned exception if there is no matching text i.e. "Summary: ".

You may want to open the 2nd file and verify that this text is present there.